# Is it possible to directly embed an image into a Markdown document?

Tags: markdown

I know that I can display an image with the following syntax:

```
![](/imagepath)
```

However, is it also possible to directly embed an image into the document to share the Markdown document with the image file directly contained inside it?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, using [`data:` URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) and base64. Terribly inefficient though:

```
![Hello World](data:image/png;base64,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)
```

Unfortunately Super User does not allow `data:` URIs, it would look like this:

> [image]

Whether this will work of course depends on whatever you’re using to (pre)view the document. It has to support and allow `data:` URIs.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! Do you know of any popular Markdown editors that can interpret and display this format?

Comment: @orschiro Unfortunately not, sorry. I just write Markdown by hand. However, in theory, any editor that “compiles” the document to HTML and displays that should do.

Comment: Maybe worth adding that if you use the "[Reference-style image syntax](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img)", you can at least bury the base64 code at the bottom of your Markdown page. `![My image up in the page][1]` followed at some point by `[1]: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...`

Comment: Looks correct on sintax. But some services will handle this incorrectly (like Github wiki, for example)

Comment: Works in [Typora](https://typora.io/)

Comment: did not work in databricks notebook :(

Answer (score 6):

I did some tests and embedding usually works with online markdown editors like *dillinger.io, jbt.github.io, stackedit.io*, so this topic isn't so black and white as @Spiff wrote above.

This is a screenshot of two base64 blocks inserted by using *1)* an internal reference and *2)* a common image insertion (see the code below).

[image: pngtesters]

*1) the referenced base64 block stops being parsed right at the point where 'a new chunk of image' starts, the green part `... So4Z4wxkXa7KukmKul2dDvd ...`

2) by passing the block directly we get the whole image*

**code**

```
1\)![png tester1][pngtester1] 2\)![png tester2](data:image/png;base64,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)

_1\) the referenced base64 block stops being parsed right at the point where 'a new chunk of image' starts, the green part `... So4Z4wxkXa7KukmKul2dDvd ...`  
2\) by passing the block directly we get the whole image_

This was tested with http://tmpvar.com/markdown.html. I don't know how it behaves on github. [The issue](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/270) has been already well discussed.

[pngtester1]:data:image/png;base64,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
```

This was tested with http://tmpvar.com/markdown.html. For the behavior on github, [the issue](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/270) has been already well discussed (and rejected).

Answer (score -4):

No, a Markdown document is just a text file, and text editors (even Markdown-savvy ones) wouldn't know what to do with a blob of binary image data in the middle of a text file.

There are methods like MIME and base64 to encode binary data into a text file in a sense, but most text editors and Markdown-renderers wouldn't know what to do with a MIME encoded document that contains a Markdown text part and a base64 encoded image part.